# helper method to check if a record is owned by the current user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, view-helpers

i'm bulding a rails 3 app, i'm using devise for manage the auth logics but i was wonder if there is a helper method to check if the current user owns an object (a record into db) that has an association "has_many".

example:

```
User

has_many :reports
```

i have this situation:

```
<%=  current_user.id == report.user.id ? "Personal Report" : report.user.username %>
```

is possible to create something like:

```
<%= owned ? "yes" : "no" %>
```

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Helper:

```
def owned(report)
    current_user.id == report.user_id
end
```

Usage:

```
<%= owned(report) ? "yes" : "no" %>
```

Comment: it can't work because the helper can't know the associated methods of report model outside the view and i don't wont to pass the report.user.user_id like param. each times i use the owned helper

Comment: @davelab Helper methods are treated like if they were declared in the view. So they can access the passed object.

Comment: @davelab if you have access to the report in the view, you can user this helper method

Answer (score 6):

You could define this method in your `Report` model:

## Model restricted:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

  def owned_by?(user)
    self.user_id == (user.try(:id) || user)
  end
```

And then use it like this:

```
<%= report.owned_by?(current_user) ? 'yes' : 'no' %>
```

This `owned_by?(user)` method accepts both a User object AND an Integer (user_id).

## Generic method for each model that has an association with User:

A helper method would do the trick:

```
module OwnerHelper
  def is_owner?(object)
    return nil if(current_user.nil? || !object.respond_to(:user_id))
    current_user.try(:id) == object.try(:user_id)
  end
end
```

This helper will return `true` if `current_user` is owner, false if not and `nil` if `current_user` is `nil` OR the object has no `user_id` attribute.

Comment: Small typo: you used `owner_by` in the method definition and your explanation. Tried to fix it myself, but edits have to change at least 6 characters.

Comment: i'd like to have a general method for each model that has the association with users.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Well done on the generic method, really nice !! : )